# Bidder expectation

Tags: probability

> Suppose $n$ people are bidding on a mystery prize that is up for auction. The bids are to be submitted in secret, and the individual who submits the highest bid wins the prize.
>   Each bidder receives an i.i.d. signal $X_i$, $i = 1,...,n$. The value of the prize, $V$ , is defined to be the sum of the individual bidders’ signals:
>   $V = X_1 + ··· + X_n$.
>   Assume the $X_i$ are i.i.d. $Unif(0, 1)$.
>
> (a) Before receiving her signal, what is bidder $1$’s unconditional expectation for $V$?
>
> (b) Conditional on receiving the signal X1 = x1, what is bidder 1’s expectation for $V$?
>
> (c) Suppose each bidder submits a bid equal to his or her conditional expectation for $V$  , i.e., bidder $i$ bids $E(V |X_i = x_i)$. Conditional on receiving the signal $X_1 = x_1$ and winning the auction, what is bidder $1$’s expectation for $V$?

What I did:

a) $E[V]=(n-1)/2$ because as I understand in this case $V = X_2 + ··· + X_n=>E[V]=n-1E[X_2]=(n-1)/2$.

b) $E[V|I_{x_1}=1]=n/2$ by analogy

c) $E[V|I_{x_1}=1,X_1 \ge x_j]=?$ where $j=2,...n$; $P(X_1 \ge x_j)=\frac1n$, by symmetry

Am I right in $a,b$ and can you help with $c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. $V=X_1+\dots+X_n$, so $E[V]=nE[X_1]=n/2$.

b. $E[V|X_1]=E[X_1|X_1]+E[X_2|X_1]+\dots+E[X_n|X_1]=X_1+1/2+\dots+1/2=X_1+(n-1)/2$.

c. The winner of the auction is the whose bid, $X_i+(n-1)/2$, is the largest. This means whichever person received the largest signal $X_i$ is the winner. Conditional on bidder 1 winning, all that bidder 1 knows is that everyone else's signal is less than theirs, so each $X_j$ is uniform over $[0,x_1]$ conditional on $X_1=x_1$ and bidder $1$ winning. The expectation of each other score is therefore $x_1/2$, so $E[V|X_1=x_1,\text{bidder }1\text{ wins}]=x_1+(n-1)x_1/2.$